# How to store rich text editor's data in Firestore?

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am working on a Medium clone app for which I will be using a rich text editor to let users enter different types of data. The types of data will include images, bold text, italics text, quote text and a lot more.

Now my question is:

How can data of different types be stored in Firestore?

Comment: how did you solve your problem if you did solve. Am curious

Answer (score -1):

I think this is all too late but nevertheless maybe my backup someday if I forget how

```
PostForm.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {

e.preventDefault();
const actualContent = $('#postEditor .jodit_container .jodit_workplace .jodit_wysiwyg').html();
```

and going down I have something like this

```
data.collection('collectionname').add({
  Title:formPostEditor['title'].value,
  Content:actualContent
```

I am just at the beginning of this so I can't say I will be able to respond. I cannot seem to get it to work in Vanilla JS just yet so I had to resort to jQuery.

Comment: Please keep your posts succinct but explain how your code works and how it solves the problem.